# Как использовать переменные одного класса в другом?

Tags: python, классы

От лирики сразу к делу...

Есть вот такой код(палками не кидайтесь, вторую неделю начинаю изучать python):

```
from random import randint

class Balance(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.money()
        self.input_bet()

    def run(self):
        self.input_bet = None

    def input_bet(self):

            input_bet = input('Ваша ставка: \n')

            try:
                input_bet = int(input_bet)
                self.input_bet = input_bet
            except Exception:
                print('Не число')


    def money(self) -> None:
        money = 10000
        print("Ваш баланс:" + str(money))

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Roulette(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.__choice_num = None
        self.__twist_num = None

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.input_number()
            self.twist_roulette()
            self.check_choice_num()

    def input_number(self) -> None:

        is_num = False
        while not is_num:
            number = input('Введите целое число от 0 до 36 \n')

            try:
                number = int(number)
                is_num = True
                self.choice_num = number
            except Exception:
                print('Опаньки...Что-то ты сделал не так...\n')

    def twist_roulette(self) -> None:
        self.twist_num = randint(0,1)

    def check_choice_num(self) -> None:
        if self.choice_num == self.twist_num:
            print('Ты победил: выпало число ' + str(self.twist_num))
            return

        print('Ты проиграл: выпало число ' + str(self.twist_num))
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
balance = Balance()
balance.run()
roulette = Roulette()
roulette.run()
```

Задумка следующая:
Нужно создать класс самой игры, в котором мы обращаемся к классу Roulette и сравниваем 2 переменные с числами для дальнейшей работы с балансом (выпало наше число = профит / выпало что-то другое = мы в уходим в минус)....

И вот конкретно сама проблема заключается в обращении к классу и конкретным аргументам... Пытался разными способами но ничего не выходит :(

Comment: 1) Если честно, то сомнительной выглядит идея на второй неделе изучения языка браться за классы. 2) лучше все же помещать тут примеры своих неудачных способов, тогда ответ может отталкиваться от них.

Comment: Тут со слов товарища "лучше сразу привыкать, дабы потом было проще" 
Что касаемо 2х недель, то то с питоном, так был опыт и с react и чутка c#

Comment: Классы использовать можно и на первой неделе обучения, тем более тут они очень подходят.

Comment: Также последний из примеров : 
    def input_bet(self):

            input_bet = input('Ваша ставка: \n')

            try:
                input_bet = int(input_bet)
                self.input_bet = input_bet
            except Exception:
                print('Не число')


    def money(self) -> None:
        money = 10000
        print("Ваш баланс:" + str(money))

Comment: Проект интересный, могу немного помочь советом в каком направлении двигаться.

Comment: Как минимум надо исправить логику рулетки, там выбирается число от 0 до 1, а пользователю предлагает от 0 до 36(или это так и задумано)

Comment: Был бы очень рад услышать :)
 Также попутно хочу спросить касаемо проверки на число, как ее инициализировать в классе с балансом? 
Изначально класс с самой рулеткой помог написать товарищ, а уже сам баланс делал подсматривая на рулетку

Comment: Диапазон выбран для проверки работы ставок (как видите - пока все тщетно)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение конкретно для работы с объектом класса в другом классе:

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self, roulette, balance):
        self._roullette = roulette
        self._balance = balance
    
    def run(self):
        self._roullette.run()
        self._balance.run()
        # do something

balance = Balance()
roulette = Roulette()

game = Game(roulette, balance)
game.run()
```

Можно хранить в поле(переменной класса) обьект другого класса и работать с ним как обычно.
Но думаю если цель сделать такую программу как вы описали, то этого будет не достаточно. Код в целом не плох для 2-ух недель обучения, но видно что сама логика работы программы не сильно продумана. Лучше реализовать классы так что бы можно было легко к ним обращатся из вне и потом все сгрупировать в класс Game.

Comment: Что думаете насчет сноски каждого класса в отдельный файл и дальнейший их вызов в main через import?

Comment: Не помешало бы, больше плюсов чем минусов. Но в своих мини-проектах особой разницы нет.

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую !